# Iteration stuck at the 16512th iteration when 100000 iterations are supposed to be made

Tags: c

I am pretty flabbergasted as to why my code got stuck at the 16512th iteration even though it seemed to have no syntactical problems. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*C version of Newton-Raphson method*/
float sqrt(float num);

main() 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        printf("%d: %.3f\n", i, sqrt(i));
    }
}

float sqrt(float num)

{
    float guess, e, upperbound;
    guess = 1;
    e = 0.001;
    do 
    {
        upperbound = num / guess;
        guess = (upperbound + guess) / 2;
    } while (!(guess * guess >= num - e && 
               guess * guess <= num + e));
    return guess;
}
```

The code is supposed to find the square-root of all numbers from 1 to 100000 using the Newtonian-Raphson method, but nothing happened after the 16152th iteration. I am using the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 to compile my scripts, if that information is of any help. Enlightenment will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: I would expect if you change your `float`s to `double`s, the problem will fix itself...

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger? At a glance, I'd guess execution is getting stuck somewhere in the loop within `sqrt`, probably not hitting the exit condition, possibly because of rounding issues.

Comment: Your mistake here is using a fixed tolerance for `e` and assuming that `float`s have infinite precision.

Comment: ScottMermelstein: Hey thanks! But can you enlighten me on what the problem is? I know that float numbers, based on the information I have read, can hold values within +- 10E37. However, my values (guess * guess) will never exceed the boundaries. Can you fill me in?

Comment: @PaulR is correct. For a `float` you don't have the precision to expect a `0.001` tolerance on a number that's too large. You could either use `double` to increase the maximum significant digites, or define your tolerance as a small percentage of the original number.

Comment: `float` can "hold" +-10E37 but that doesn't mean you get significant digits down to the the 1's place in such numbers, let alone thousandths decimal place. You need to consider significant digits. A `double` will give you more significant digits and increase the maximum sized number your algorithm will work with.

Comment: Paul R: Hi Paul, Thanks for the answer, but can you explain what you just said means? I don't get that problem when I am using Python or Javascript so I am quite befuddled right now.

Comment: Python uses double-precision floats. So does JavaScript, probably.

Comment: There is a ; misplaced in `sqrt()`.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to make your code look as good as you can when asking questions on SO.  It is worth spending time removing obvious blemishes, even trivial ones like a stray semi-colon that is harmless.  It is hard to be sure whether you know that it is weird, so people will point out oddities in your code.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: I will be mindful of that. Thanks for your advice. =D

Comment: On my compiler it is iterating only up to 7804!

Comment: @mbratch; Did you find any reason behind this. I tried my times to by doing some modification but nothing happened to the output!

Comment: @haccks I didn't dig into it much. I found that by using `e = 0.002` I come very close to the OP's `16395` iterations. Close. ;) But perhaps it has to do with the compiler and order of operations as to how much precision is lost per iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, when I posted mycomment, it was more a hunch than real knowledge.  The algorithm was valid, so something must be making the while loop not terminate, and since you were properly using epsilons, we were hitting the limits from the float.

@PaulR's comments make it make more sense.  The sqrt of 16512 is 128.499027233672...  Float has fairly limited precision, so it wasn't getting anything within .001 of that number.  It makes even more sense if you think of an even bigger number, e.g. sqrt(123455555.54321) (which is 11111.11111).  Floating point precision won't necessarily even get you to the 11111, let alone 11111.111.

Changing to double "fixes" this, but just kicks the can down the road.  Somewhere later on, we'd have the same precision issue, and this algorithm should work on any size number.

@mrbratch brings up the robust solution - define your tolerance as a percentage of the number.  If you set `e = num * 0.00001`, your loop will always complete.  Obviously, you can play with epsilon and tweak it to your satisfaction.  And note, for big numbers, this can give you an integer that's not even the closest int to the right answer.

I can't speak for python, but I can confirm that [javascript uses double precision](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).

Comment: Fyi, double precision has 15-17 significant digits of precesion.  So you'll almost certainly fail if, e.g. you try to find sqrt(12345678901234567^2).  (Put a decimal place anywhere in that, you'll get the same issue.)

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the comments, the problem is because you can't have that much precision (0.001) with any number. In particular, when the number is large enough, only the most important digits are saved. See the IEEE 754 standard if you want more information about how it works. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Now, I'd recommend that you use a percentage of error for the tolerance:

```
float sqrt(float num)

{
    float guess, e, upperbound;
    guess = 1;
    e = 0.001;
    do 
    {
        upperbound = num / guess;
        guess = (upperbound + guess) / 2;
    } while (!(guess * guess / num >= 1 - e && 
               guess * guess / num <= 1 + e));
    return guess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the squaring causes loss of precision:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*C version of Newton-Raphson method*/
float mysqrt(float num); /* avoid conflicts with built-in sqrt() if any */

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        printf("%d: %.3f\n", i, (double)mysqrt(i)); /* cast to double, since printf() is varargs */
    }
return 0;
}


float mysqrt(float num)
{
    float newguess, e, oldguess;
    e = 0.001;
    newguess = 1.0;
    do
    {
        oldguess = newguess;
        newguess = (num/oldguess + newguess ) / 2;
        /* compare tor the previous value; avoid squaring */
    } while (newguess / oldguess > (1+e) || oldguess / newguess > (1+e) );
    // } while (newguess < oldguess -e || newguess > oldguess +e); // "mostly works"
    return newguess;
}
```

Comment: `(double)` is not needed as `float` arguments to `printf()` are already promoted to `double`.

Comment: That is correct. I am still very cautious about vararg functions, even given default type promotions.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple adjustment**

Use *relative* Floating Point precision, not absolute.

There area as many FP representable numbers between 0.001 and 0.002 as between 1,000 and 2,000.  So when calculating square root, the iterations should depend on the local relative error.

Do not use absolute error bounds like `e = 0.001`, but relative ones.  Code then runs just fine.

```
// e = 0.001;
e = 0.001 * num;
```

---

[edit] I know see @Scott Mermelstein has a similar comment.